# Relative dualizing sheaf (References)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

do you know any reference for the relative dualizing sheaf of a family of curves? I´ve been looking through the literature and I can not find anything. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Hartshorne's *Residues and Duality* is the classic original reference for Grothendieck duality. It has a number of technical issues, which are fixed in Brian Conrad's *Grothendieck Duality and Base Change*, available on the web for free from the author's [website](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/). These texts are very general - if you're looking for something more specific, please clarify your question.

Comment: I need to study the dualizing sheaf of the projection  $X\times S\rightarrow S$, where X is a projective smooth curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and beeing $S$ a $k$-scheme. I will need the case of a  proper and flat morphism $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$, between k-schemes, such that, the fibers are integral curves of genus $g$.

Comment: Both books mentioned in this post will cover enough material for you to attack the mentioned situation.